# Autocorrelation problem in multiple regression on SPSS

Tags: multiple-regression

What is autocorrelation and how it can effect the results of multiple regression in ***SPSS***. Durbin-Watson value of **1.04** is acceptable or not? If this value effects the results, then how to **correct** it in SPSS.

Comment: Where exactly does this value of 1.04 come from? Is it perhaps the Durbin-Watson statistic?

Answer (score 1):

An autocorrelation of lag1 in the residuals of 1.04 suggests that one or more of your series might require differencing. It may also suggest that you don't have the right lag structure in one or more of your input series. It could also be due to an omitted level shift or local time trend in one or more of your series.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am puzzled: how can an autocorrelation (presumably the lag-one coefficient) exceed $1$ in size?

Comment: Yes, it is Durbon-Watson statistic. I am asking in the context of Durbin-Watson statistic.

Comment: @whuber Since the coefficients are "free to vary" , it is possible to have an AR(1) coefficient exceed unity BUT as you correctly point out the acf(1) can not exceed 1.0 .